# "How much of a problem"

Tags: questions

Is it grammatically correct to ask, "how much of a problem is this?", ... and is this something that can only be used in spoken English, or is it also permissible in writing? Thanks!

Comment: @bak1936 please don't answer questions incorrectly. "Much" is not a pronoun in this case. "How much" is perfectly fine.

Comment: What is "this"? Some additional context would be helpful. Maybe write a more complete example.

Comment: Seems grammatically correct. That exact phrase does sound colloquial, more often used in spoken English.